# Renaming postgres table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I wonder if it is possible to rename Postgres table without cascading type change to dependent objects? For example,

```
create table test_1(id int);
create function test_1_funct (param test_1[]) returns void as $body$
begin
    return;
end 
$body$
language plpgsql;
alter table test_1 rename to test_2 ; 
 -- function test_1_funct signature silently changed, 
 -- so it now accepts test_2[].
```

I want to emulate behaviour similar to what Oracle would do - mark function invalid, let me create table with the old name, and recompile the function on demand .  As it is, it doesn't let me `drop table test_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. Not should it be. Tables resolve to an oid that represents their relation.

```
SELECT 'test_1'::regclass::oid;
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname = 'test_1';
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE oid = 'test_1'::regclass::oid;
```

Changing their "name" is essentially a catalog update on `relname`. How would what you're talking about look anyway: what would happen if you called `test_1_funct` after the rename? What type would it expect?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to get a runtime error. It'd save lots of time while doing , for instance , existing table partitioning...